# Reload upon selecting Date

Tags: custom-form

I was hoping someone could suggest what I can do in order to refresh the EditForm page after the user Selects a date..? Thanks in advance.

Brandon

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this - whats the goal?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with the out-of-the-box as much as possible you could Edit your form to add a CEWP (Content Editor) which could link to a Javascript using the standard `javascript:__doPostBack('<get ID of the DATETIME control>','');` method call available in every ASP.NET page (use F12 IE Developer Tools to get the Client ID generated in the page by the control hierarchy - it should start with _ctlXXXX)